# Can't click link that is underneath transparent divs (in FireFox or IE)

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with this site:

https://connectiveworldenergy.com/

At the top of the page, there is some text saying "Design a happy life and create a stress free path that you've always dreamed of.
Let us show you how!". It is a clickable link.

On FireFox and IE, the link is not clickable.

I think it might have something to do with z-Index. The menu is overlapping on top of it. I've tried adjusting Z-index but haven't had luck. So then I read about z-index and it appears z-index requires elements to have the same "position"

The elements on top of it are transparent background... not sure why it's not clickable.

Comment: transparent doesn't mean not there. it will block it just like a glass pane blocks what's on the other side.

Comment: The problem is your `display: inline-block` on `#et-secondary-nav` and its `<li>` children. That's causing the secondary nav to display on top of the ribbon (and the link in question).

Comment: add `pointer-events:none` to the transparent div

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements: `.cwe-ribbon` (your clickable link) and `#top-header' (the rest of your header).

You gave `#top-header` a z-index of 100 so `.cwe-ribbon` (your clickable link) will need to be greater than this to sit on top of the other element (and be clickable).

set the `z-index` of `.cew-ribbon` to 101. In order for `z-index` to work you need to give the element a position so go ahead set it to `position: relative`.